# How to improve these nested for loops

Tags: c++, performance, loops, sorting

I have the following code:

```
// vector of elements
vector<Graphic> graphics;

// vector of indexes of the selected graphic elements
vector<int> selected_indexes;

// vector according to which the graphic elements have to be "sorted" and parsed
vector<short> order;

for (auto o : order)
{
    for (auto i : selected_indexes)
    {
        const auto& g = graphics[i];

        if (g.position() == o)
        {
            // parse g
        }
    }
}
```

I have a vector of custom elements as well as the indexes of the elements that have been selected to be parsed, but the order in which these elements have to be parsed depends on their `position()` value according to a third vector.

Is there a way to improve these nested loops, avoiding to iterate over and over on elements that will be skipped because their position is not equal to the current order?

Comment: The improvements you are looking for, are they speed (execution time), readability or "elegance"?

Comment: @Niall I am looking for speed improvements.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming there's only one `Graphic` object with a given `position()`:

Build an `unordered_map` : `int` → `Graphics*`, that you call e.g. `gp`, so that `gp[i]->position()` = `i`.

Building the map is linear time, using it for each index is constant time, roughly.

```
for( auto o : order )
{
    auto const& g = *gp[o];
    // parse g
}
```

If there can be more than one `Graphics` object with a given position, build an `unordered_map` : `int` → `vector<Graphic*>`, then with usage code like

```
for( auto o : order )
{
    for( auto const p : gp[o] )
    {
        auto const& g = *p;
        // parse g
    }
}
```

Or, for the last case you might use an `unordered_multimap`.

Comment: Naively building the map is linear in the number of graphics.  The OP's code is O(MN) but M is selection size and N is order size, it is O(1) in number of graphics.  Hm: when building, build from vector of indexes selected only.  That gets you down to O(M+N)?  Yep.

Comment: O-Notation is not everything though in c++. Depending on the size having a vector and sorting it and then iterating can be faster than iterating a huge map.

Answer (score 3):

You already know how many elements you want to process, so you can use a vector that keeps pointers to your `Graphic` instances, already allocated with the appropriate number of elements:

```
vector<Graphic*> selected(selected_indexes.size(), nullptr);
```

Then you can fill this vector with the elements, sorted using `order`:

```
for (auto index: selected_indexes) {
  auto where = std::find_if(order.begin(), order.end(), [&graphics, index] (short i) { return i == graphics[index].position(); });
  selected[*where] = &graphics[index];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of nesting these you could create a temporary vector and do this step by step.

```
vector<Graphic> selectedGraphics; //maybe use ptr here
selectedGraphics.reserve(selected_indexes.size());
for(auto i : selected_indexes)
    selectedGraphics.push_back(graphics[i]);

//then sort according to your order
std::sort(selectedGraphics.begin(),selectedGraphics.end(),[order](auto left, auto right)
{
    //the iterator of the position of "left" is further in front of the position of "right"
    return order.find(left.position()) < order.find(right.position());
});

//then process
for(auto graphic : selectedGraphics)
    //do whatever
```

The sort assumes, that the `order` vector entries and the ones which are `selectedGraphics` match. I am not sure if there will be any strange side effects if an selected graphic object has a position which is not in the `order` vector.

Comment: Could you expand the sort procedure? (An example of the vector order {2, 1, 3, 0, 4, 5}).

Comment: OK I edited the answer. It should work like that. I cant test it though.

Comment: I also added the `reserve` for completeness sake.